# Sum and product in the variance of exponential distribution

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3$ be independent r.v with $X_i \sim \ exp(1)$, evaluate $$\text{Var}[(X_1+X_2)X_3].$$

I tryed to use $$\text{Var}[(X_1+X_2)X_3]= E[((X_1+X_2)X_3)^2]-(E[(X_1+X_2)X_3])^2$$

But i keep finding 8 when the textbook gives the answer $\text{Var}[(X_1+X_2)X_3]=6$. Any hint for this?

Comment: Yes, i will edit this.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to use the law of total variance:
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}[(X_1+X_2)X_3] 
&= \operatorname{Var}[\operatorname{E}[(X_1 + X_2)X_3 \mid X_3]] + \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}[(X_1 + X_2)X_3 \mid X_3]] \\
&= \operatorname{Var}[X_3 \operatorname{E}[X_1 + X_2]] + \operatorname{E}[X_3^2 \operatorname{Var}[X_1 + X_2]] \\
&\overset{\text{ind}}{=} \operatorname{Var}[X_3 (\operatorname{E}[X_1] + \operatorname{E}[X_2])] + \operatorname{E}[X_3^2 (\operatorname{Var}[X_1] + \operatorname{Var}[X_2])] \\
&=\operatorname{Var}[X_3(1 + 1)] + \operatorname{E}[X_3^2 (1 + 1)] \\
&= \operatorname{Var}[2X_3] + \operatorname{E}[2X_3^2] \\
&= 4 \operatorname{Var}[X_3] + 2 (\operatorname{Var}[X_3] + \operatorname{E}[X_3]^2) \\
&= 6 + 2 \\
&= 8.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Are you sure that this is right? I find the same result but the answer in the book is 6.

Comment: @Lucascantu Yes, $8$ is correct.  The book is wrong.  You can also verify it by simulation.  For instance, generate $3n$ iid realizations from an exponential distribution with mean $1$, group them into triplets $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$, then compute $(x_1 + x_2)x_3$.  This gives $n$ realizations from the desired distribution.  Then calculate the sample variance.  For large $n$, you will get a number very close to $8$.

Comment: Thank you! It was really helpfull.